# How can I send Animation-Packet with ProtocolLib in Spigot?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I want to show a damage animation on a entity without damage.
NOT:

```
entity.damage(2);
```

and then

```
public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent event) {
    event.setDamage(0);
```

more like that:

```
entity.setHealth(entity.getHealth - 2);
"Send a packet to Player Damage Animation IF POSSIBLE WITH ProtocolLib"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`Player.damage`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Damageable.html#damage(double)) method to make everything as "normal".

If you want to send your own packet, yous should use the `PacketPlayOutAnimation`, with the value `1` ([Why?](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Entity_Animation_.28clientbound.29))

For 1.16 and lower:

```
import net.minecraft.server.MC_VERSION.PacketPlayOutAnimation;

EntityPlayer ep = ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle();
ep.playerConnection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutAnimation(ep, 1));
```

For 1.17 and more:

```
import net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.PacketPlayOutAnimation;

EntityPlayer ep = ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle();
ep.b.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutAnimation(ep, 1));
```

Here is a version with import of direct minecraft version. You can use [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) to use those [NMS](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/204127/) for all versions.

Or with ProtocolLib, it seems to be something like that:

```
PacketContainer packetContainer = protocolManager.createPacket(Play.Server.ANIMATION);
packetContainer.getIntegers().write(0, entityId);
packetContainer.getIntegers().write(0, 1);
manager.sendServerPacket(p, packetContainer); // seems to be how you send packet
```

More informations about the packet in ProtocolLib [here](https://github.com/dmulloy2/ProtocolLib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/comphenix/protocol/PacketType.java#L112)

Comment: In this case I get this error:                                 com.comphenix.protocol.reflect.FieldAccessException: No field with type byte exists in class PacketPlayOutAnimation

Comment: Well, no there is no stacktrace, but nothing happens. No damage animation :(

Comment: The problem. I coding a Weapon plugin. And the weapon shoot snowballs. And if use player.damage(2): When the snowball reach the target the target get damage the damage animation plays. And if while the damage animation run a snowball reach the target also the damage dont arrive

Comment: I dont understand sorry

Comment: No, I can also manage this without ProtocolLib

Comment: My IDE means "Cannot resolve symbol 'playerConnection'"

Comment: newest paper version: 1.18.1

Comment: Ok, the answer was working from 1.8 to 1.16. I just update the answer for 1.18. Also, I removed some comment.